Desmos arbitrarily caps list of polygons
I have a graph in which polygons are generated underneath four curves to create a trapezoidal approximation. However, moving the slider variable (c) past a value of 186 has no effect on the polygons. The list that the variable c controls continues to change size, but no more polygons are generated. Why does Desmos arbitrarily cap the polygons at this value? I do have Desmodder for Desmos installed, but I don't think that would affect anything.
Here is the link to my graph:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oq2wvdqblp
I have tried making the list [c...d] instead of [d...c], but that still has the capping effect, it just moves the polygons with the slider once it reaches 186 instead.

The reason is due  to the colors. Since the list c1 only has 186 elements, desmos can only graph that many items. Changing the color to one of the default colors makes all the polygons appear.
I am not sure how to get all the colors, but rgb([0...c],0,0) works fairly well.
